# Hartl tutorial Ch. 8 the dropdown menu via javascript will not drop down and user cannot log out

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I have checked the code over and over again, but I cannot seem to find why the dropdown menu will not work.  And because of that, I can't see if the links in the dropdown menu function correctly. Also, the header now cuts off the

. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     log_in user
     redirect_to user 
    else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
    end
    end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

sessions helper

```
module SessionsHelper
    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end
    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end
end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'test-unit'

gem 'rails-perftest'

gem 'minitest'

gem 'bcrypt'

gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Use SCSS for stylesheets
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do 
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'mini_backtrace'
  gem 'guard-minitest'


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: I know the tutorial tells you to install bootstrap using the gem, but I have found myself in a lot of trouble because of using it instead of downloading manually the framework (css, js files) and importing them by myself, including an error I had with a dropdown menu.
So I urge you to uninstall bootstrap gem and reinstall it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these 2 lines at the top of your custom.css.scss file?

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

Your _header.html.erb works fine in my app. Only difference I can see here is that you use: 
gem 'bootstrap-sass' 
and I use: 
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

When the user is not seen as logged in, the dropdown menu will not show.

You didn't post your ApplicationController file.
Did you add

```
include SessionsHelper
```

in the ApplicationController? I think it is needed for the log in method.

Answer (score 0):

Go and login a whatever user, and check out the source page see if you have doubled  and all its following stuff. They are duplicated in the application.html.erb file. If you go to your application.html.erb and comment out the header and all its content, and refresh the page, and check it again, the drop down links should show up. The problem here is, that in the tutorial it did not mention anything, but as the steps in the book you have created this header in previous chapter. So the header in the application file takes the priority and it block the _header.html.erb file content.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu is not showing because bootstrap requires jquery as a dependency (order of your requires matters in application.js). Putting `require bootstrap` after `require jquery_ujs` should fix the problem.

Comment: Please See this First. [How-do-I-write-a-good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, following the book to "t", got to chapter 8 and tried everything under the sun. I decided to step away and play some Destiny2 and in the midst of slaying newbs it came to me. "//" in a *.js (JavaScript file) are single line comments. Check out the official W3School info on it [JavaScript Comments](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp)

**So all you need to do is remove the "//" from all line entries in the application.js file.**

Should look like this instead:

```
   = require jquery
   = require bootstrap
   = require rails-ujs
   = require turbolinks
   = require_tree .
```